# How to make html <p> tag not add a newline but a trailing space in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some text blocks to be displayed in the same line. I tried to wrap up them so that I do not need to add white spaces between them. However, when I tried `<p>`, it seems that will do a line break. Is there anyway to change that to a trailing space, or using other tags to achieve the goal?

Comment: use `span` instead of `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this is done with unordered list elements `<li></li>` wrapped in `<ul></<ul>` and styled in CSS to be `display:inline;`.

Then you can add your `left-margin` or `right-margin` values as you prefer for spacing.

```html
    <style>
    ul li {
      display: inline;
      margin-right: 10px;
      color: blue;
    }
    </style>
    
    <ul>
      <li>Some Text</li>
      <li>More Text</li>
      <li>Some More</li>
    <ul>
```

Comment: I turn that into `li` and `ul` and set the display inline stuff. However, it still seems every instance is displayed in a new line. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your inheritance on your li elements is most likely incorrect. See the example I just added.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a non-breaking space using `&nbsp;`

```html
Text&nbsp;Text
```

You can also use an element's `margin` properties to set its distance from the nearest element (there are four `margin` properties: `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-right`, and `margin-left`).

```html
<span>Text text text</span><span style="margin-left: 30px;">More text more text</span>
```

You can use `display: inline-block` to make elements stay on the same line. Just alter the `margin-right` and `margin-left` properties to adjust the space between the elements.

```css
.square{
 width: 50px; 
 height: 50px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square" style="margin-left: 300px;"></div>
```